# Ruby constant resolution not finding constant defined in class ancestor when method is defined in included module

Tags: ruby

Ruby constant resolution is a deep topic (see [Rails Conf 2022 talk by Xavier Noria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzyGdOd_6-Y)); however, in a nutshell, it can be summarized by "first nesting outwards, and then ancestor chain upwards".

Take the following code:

```rb
module Insurable
  LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT = 150_000
end

class Person
  DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE = 18
end

class BusDriver < Person
  include Insurable
  def can_drive_from
    "Can drive from #{DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE}, with life insurance of $#{LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT}"
  end
end

BusDriver.new.can_drive_from
=> "Can drive from 18, with life insurance of $150000"
```

As you can see, `#can_drive_from` can find the constant `DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE` without any issues; even tough it's not in it's Module.nesting (first rule - nesting outwards), `Person` is an ancestor of `BusDriver`, and so using the second rule (ancestor chain upwards) it finds `Person::DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE`.

However, if you just move the method to the included module like this:

```rb
module Insurable
  LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT = 150_000
  def can_drive_from
    "Can drive from #{DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE}, with life insurance of $#{LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT}"
  end
end

class Person
  DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE = 18
end

class BusDriver < Person
  include Insurable
end

BusDriver.new.can_drive_from

NameError: uninitialized constant Insurable::DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE

    "Can drive from #{DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE}, with life insurance of $#{LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT}"
```

I was under the impression that Ruby would traverse the ancestor chain of `BusDriver`, which includes `Person`, and find the constant there (second rule). What changed that made Ruby ignore the ancestor chain here?

Answer (score 3):

This is my understanding of constant lookup in ruby:

1. First check Module Nesting ("first nesting outwards")
2. Second check the open module or class, ancestral chain ("ancestor chain upwards")

> I was under the impression that Ruby would traverse the ancestor chain of `BusDriver`, which includes `Person`, and find the constant there (second rule). What changed that made Ruby ignore the ancestor chain here?

Ruby did not ignore the ancestral chain instead your implementation caused this chain to kind of "branch" at `Insurable`.

When you `include Insurable` this module is injected into the ancestral chain for `BusDriver` between `BusDriver` and `Person`; however this does not modify the ancestral chain for `Insurable` itself.

```
[BusDriver, Insurable, Person, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When you call `BusDriver.new.can_drive_from`:

- It checks `BusDriver` instance methods first and cannot find `#can_drive_from`.
- It then checks `Insurable` instance methods which does define `#can_drive_from`.

Now here is where it seems you might be tripped up. The method definition is in the module `Insurable`, and this is where the constant reference occurs, so based on our "rules":

- Check `Insurable` module nesting -> No constant `DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE` here
- Check `Insurable` ancestral chain -> No constant `DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE` here
- Error

This is because the "open module" that defines `#can_drive_from` is `Insurable` and as mentioned prior the inclusion of `Insurable` in another class does not impact the ancestral chain for `Insurable` it only impacts the ancestral chain of the including `Module`/`Class`.

You can further recognize this as follows:

```
class Person; DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE = 18; end

module X
  DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE = 99
  module Insurable
    LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT = 150_000
    def can_drive_from
      "Can drive from #{DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE}, with life insurance of $#{LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT}"
    end
  end
end 

class CarDriver < Person; include X::Insurable; end

module BMX
  DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE = 8
  class BikeRider < Person
    LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT = 10_000
    def can_drive_from
      "Can drive from #{DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE}, with life insurance of $#{LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT}"
    end 
  end 
end 

CarDriver.ancestors 
#=> [BusDriver, X::Insurable, Person, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]

CarDriver.new.can_drive_from
#=> "Can drive from 99, with life insurance of $150000"

BMX::BikerRider.new.can_drive_from 
#=> "Can drive from 8, with life insurance of $10000"
```

Note:

- that `X` is not part of the ancestral chain for `CarDriver`; however `X` is part of `X::Insurable`'s module nesting so `X::Insurable#can_drive_from` is able to resolve `DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE` as `X::DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE`.
- `BikerRider` inherits from `Person` which defines `Person::DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE`; however `BikeRider`'s module nesting is `[BMX::BikeRider, BMX]` and `BMX` defines `DRIVING_LICENSE_AGE`. Since Module nesting is checked first this definition overrides the direct inheritance when you call `#can_drive_from`